# Check existence of given text in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, table-functions

I have a course code name COMP2221.

I also have a function `finder(int)` that can find all codes matching a certain pattern.

Like:

```
select * from finder(20004)
```

will give:

```
comp2211
comp2311
comp2411
comp2221
```

which match the pattern `comp2###`.

My question is how to express "whether comp2221 is in finder(20004)" in a neat way?

Comment: What do you mean "how to interpret "whether comp2221 is in finder(20004)" in a neat way?" What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like I want to write `if(comp2221 IN select * from finder(20004))` but it is in wrong syntax, how to express it in plpgsql way

Comment: Check out the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to express "whether comp2221 is in finder(20004)" in a neat way?

Use an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression and put the test into the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM finder(20004) AS t(code) WHERE code = 'comp2221');
```

Returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Never NULL and never more than one row - even if your table function `finder()` returns duplicates.

Or fork the function `finder()` to integrate the test directly. Probably faster.